# $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, uniform-continuity

> **Definition:** A function $f:A \to \mathbb R$ is *uniformly continuous* on $A$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

---

I have a question about the correct proof strategy to show that a function $f$ is uniformly continuous.

The phrase "for every $\epsilon > 0$. there exists a $\delta > 0$" suggests to me that I should start by writing $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon $ for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$,   and show **that this leads to** $|x - y| < \delta$.

But the phrase "$|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$" in the definition suggests to me I should start from the other direction.

I am little confused. Can you just tell me how to start a general proof?

Thank you.

Comment: You start by letting an arbitrary $\epsilon$ be given, then show that there is a $\delta$, usually defined in terms of the arbitrary $\epsilon$, such that...

Comment: You definitely do NOT start by assuming that $| f(x) - f(y) | < \epsilon$.

Comment: @Joe you certainly shouldn't start there when writing up the proof, but sometimes starting at the end can help you see what needs to be shown.

Comment: @Charles Hudgins, absolutely, not assuming what you’re trying to show is all that I meant to avoid. I feel like it is a common mistake when first learning to write proofs, to write what you’re trying to show, but in a way that mixes that into the proof, making it so that you have assumed the conclusion.

Comment: @Joe Definitely. I can still remember my first college math class. I cringe to think of the proofs I submitted to some of my TAs. I was just trying to make another point that is often overlooked by new mathematicians: a proof is like an essay; you can write a rough draft. In fact, I'm of the mind that you should write a rough draft if you've got the time to. Your first draft of a proof should convince yourself that the result is true. Your second draft should be able to convince someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a particular proof instead? Let's show that $f(x) = x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Observe that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| = |x^2 - y^2| = |x - y||x + y|
$$
Now, if $x,y \in [0,1]$, then $|x+y| \leq 2$. Thus, 
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 2|x - y|
$$
Now, choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2} > 0$. If $x,y \in [0,1]$ and $|x - y| < \delta$, then
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leq 2|x - y| < 2\delta = \epsilon
$$
Therefore, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

Does this shed some light on how uniform continuity is proved in general?

Comment: Suppose the function is not uniform continuous, but just continuous at a point $x$. Then, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, the $\delta$ we need to produce can depend on $x$ as well as $\epsilon$, right?

Comment: Exactly right. Precisely, the two definitions read $f : X \to Y$ is *continuous* at $c$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x \in X$ if $|x - c| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$. By contrast, $f$ is *uniformly continuous* on $A \subset X$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x,y \in A$ if $|x - y| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$. The rule is that the object after a $\exists$ can depend on everything preceding it but *cannot* depend on anything after it.

Comment: So, in continuity, $\delta$ can depend only on $c$ and $\epsilon$. In uniform continuity, $\delta$ can depend only on $A$ and $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Start with an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$. You then need to produce some $\delta > 0$ (which may depend on $\epsilon$) such that any $x$ and $y$ satisfying $|x-y| < \delta$ also satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Suppose the function is not uniform continuous, but just continuous at a point $x$. Then, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, the $\delta$ we need to produce can depend on $x$ as well as $\epsilon$, right?

Comment: @Black Yes, that's right.